# how to change local link to id in pug.js

Tags: node.js, pug

i want to set id of my data as a local link , i mean i want to replace [#section-one] to #[feature.feature_id], as you can see local link already have a #/hash and when you call your data in pug you should to use #/hash and now we can't use two ## together ! so what can i do  ?

i have tried many ways but not successes yet, in below i will show you my code

```
 .col-md-3.scroll to fixed-container
  .list-group. scroll to fixed.z-index-0
   each feature in features
    a.list-group-item.smooth-scroll-to-target(h ref=feature.feature_id) # {feature.feature_title}
.col-md-9
 each feature in features
  #section-one .mb-50    // i want replace [#section-one] to [feature.feature_id]

  h3 #{feature.feature_title}
  hr
  p.mb-20
  | #{feature.feature_content}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
each feature in features
  div(id="#{feature.feature_id}")
```

EDIT:

I'm sorry but it seems this syntax doesn't work anymore. According to the [official documentation](https://pugjs.org/language/attributes.html#attribute-interpolation) you should do it as follows:

```
each feature in features
  - var fid = feature.feature_id
  div(id=fid)
```